# How can I enforce TLS1.3 on my NATS server and reject TLS1.2 connections?

Tags: tls1.3, nats.io

I cannot find any documentation how to start a NATS server and enforce TLS1.3.

I want the NATS server to reject any connection attempts using TLS1.2 and only accept TLS1.3 connections. Is there a way to start a NATS server that enforces this?